# My Intellij idea scene builder suddenly stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

When I was working with scene builder I faced this problem that it suddenly stopped working.I closed the program and then opened the project again,and the problem was solved but this time this solution wasn't the answer.I even tried increasing the heap memory of inellijidea to 2048 but it didn't work either.Could someone give a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors when it stops?

Comment: @pam actually not

Comment: I have this issue currently on one of my laptops where it happens when I try to press the Edit on my toolbar, or if I try to Ctl+Z. It just closes. So I avoid using the undo until I can figure it out. Hoping someone can answer this

Comment: What is the IDE version? Please describe the steps you follow and the screenshot with the result you see. Also check the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) - are there any errors?